# Application name not being prefixed to signed apk - Android Studio

Tags: android

I created the signed apk using android studio but it shows as app-release.apk instead of MyAppName-release.apk. How can I add myappname to be prefixed to signed apk.

In the application folder structure in android studio, there is myappname folder then under it is the app folder which has all the java files and layout files etc. I guess it's picking name app from the folder but when I right click on it, doesn't gives me an option to change module name. I would like to add my application name in the signed apk file. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just rename the apk?

Comment: You can rename the module by selecting it and pressing Shift+F6. However, I have had some troubles with that so if you are going to try it, first make a backup of your complete project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just rename the file app-release.apk to MyAppName-release.apk, or whatever you want. By the way, this will not affect anything you see after installing the app on a device.